# Take any hash keys and flatten into mixed array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a mixed array like: `["foo", "bar", {test: "stuff"}, "foobar", {just: "examples}]`

I want to take any hashes, remove the key, and push the value into the array. Taking my example above, I want to return:

```
["foo", "bar", "stuff", "foobar", "examples"]
```

Simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ["foo", "bar", {test: "stuff"}, "foobar", {just: "examples"}]
a.flat_map { |x| x.is_a?(Hash) ? x.values : x }
# => ["foo", "bar", "stuff", "foobar", "examples"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, without `if` (which, as @Matt pointed out, only works with the hashes have a single key, as in the example):

```
a = ["foo", "bar", {test: "stuff"}, "foobar", {just: "examples"}]

a.map { |e| [*e].flatten.last }
  #=> ["foo", "bar", "stuff", "foobar", "examples"]
```

Comment: This works only if each hash only has one key/value pair. The OP did use "key" in the singular instead of the plural, so maybe that's what he had in mind, but thought this was worth mentioning in any case.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. That occurred to me. It deserves a mention.

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick but the `flatten` is `Array#flatten`. `[*{a: 1}].class # => Array`.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt, but no need to apologize. After all, nit-picking is the essence of coding. btw, I tried to modify my code to deal with hashes with multiple keys.  I want something like `a.flat_map { |e| [*e].transpose.last }`. That works for elements of the array that are hashes, but not for strings. If `a = ['cat']`, I wanted to make use of the fact that `[a].transpose.last => a` Any ideas on how to get that to work?